# Limitations in using Reduce for Integer systems

Tags: equation-solving

**The System**

For example, when solving the following system using `Reduce` in `Integers`:

```
ClearAll[b, a, o, h, integerSystem];
integerSystem[bCondition_] := Reduce[
   bCondition &&
    1 <= a[1] < b &&
    0 <= a[2] < b &&
    1 <= a[1] + o[1] < b - 1 &&
    0 <= 2 a[1] + a[2] - (-1 + b) o[1] + o[2] < b - 1 &&
    1 <= 2 a[1] + a[2] - (-1 + b) o[2] < b - 1 &&
    a[1] + o[1] == 2 a[1] + a[2] - (-1 + b) o[2] &&
    1 <= a[1] + h[1] < b - 2 &&
    0 <= 4 a[1] + a[2] - (-2 + b) h[1] + h[2] < b - 2 &&
    1 <= 5 a[1] + 2 a[2] - (-2 + b) h[2] < b - 2 &&
    a[1] + h[1] == 5 a[1] + 2 a[2] - (-2 + b) h[2],
   {a[1], a[2], o[1], o[2], h[1], h[2] (*,b*)},
   Integers];
```

**Working examples**

When solving for individual `b` it works fine:

```
Timing[integerSystem[b == 8]]
Timing[integerSystem[b == 9]]
```

**Stuck on examples - or not?**

But when using `GreaterEqual`, it gets stuck running forever:

```
Timing[integerSystem[9 >= b >= 8]]
```

Even thought the domain is specified as `Integers`, and `b` is still just either `8` or `9`.

But I have figured out a workaround:

By combining the values of `b` by `||`, we can break down the "interval":

```
Timing[integerSystem[b == 8 || b == 9]]
```

And obtain the desired result.

**Getting stuck for other reasons?**

The examples that usually work, also get stuck if `b` is added to the variables of `Reduce`.

**Questions**

> Why is `Reduce` having problems processing `b` either in an interval,
>   or as a variable?
>
> What are generally limitations in solving these types of inequalities,
>   and are there workarounds?
>
> Like for example, splitting the interval [8,9] into cases {8,9} in the
>   mentioned examples makes `Reduce` work in intervals, where at first it
>   didn't.

My goal was solving this system for `(a[1],a[2];b)` in general, but `Reduce` appears to only be able to handle this for individual values of `b` at a time.

> Is there a "workaround" for this, or is `Reduce` unable to solve this
>   system for `b` in general?
>
> Is it possible to know what aspect of the system is causing `Reduce` the most issues?

The expected solution is just:

> $$ (a_1,a_2;b)=(2+k,6+k;8+2k),k\in\mathbb N_0 $$

And for $b=9$, specially: $(3,6;9)$.

The `o[1],o[2],h[1],h[2]` can be deduced and are unique after `a[1],a[2],b` are found, so the solution is kept just in this form.

Which seems simple enough?

> Is there a way Mathematica can solve this system for
>   general $b$ and acquire the expected solution, or is it simply out of
>   its reach?

---

**Motivation**

One part curiosity, other part is the motivation  to actually solve a generalization of the above "`integerSystem`", which just represents the first case of such generalization.

I have by hand obtained and proved the expected solution mentioned above, for this first case, but I'm unable to do so for other cases and was hoping a CAS like Mathematica could help me solve (and prove I have a set of all solutions) in the generalized case in terms of general $b$ if possible - but it appears to be stuck even at this first case.

Comment: does `integerSystem2[bCondition_] := 
 Reduce[Reduce[bCondition, Integers] && 1 <= a[1] < b && 
   0 <= a[2] < b && 1 <= a[1] + o[1] < b - 1 && 
   0 <= 2 a[1] + a[2] - (-1 + b) o[1] + o[2] < b - 1 && 
   1 <= 2 a[1] + a[2] - (-1 + b) o[2] < b - 1 && 
   a[1] + o[1] == 2 a[1] + a[2] - (-1 + b) o[2] && 
   1 <= a[1] + h[1] < b - 2 && 
   0 <= 4 a[1] + a[2] - (-2 + b) h[1] + h[2] < b - 2 && 
   1 <= 5 a[1] + 2 a[2] - (-2 + b) h[2] < b - 2 && 
   a[1] + h[1] == 5 a[1] + 2 a[2] - (-2 + b) h[2], {b, a[1], a[2], 
   o[1], o[2], h[1], h[2]}, Integers]` work?

Comment: @kglr For me, it now works for small enough interval for $b$, for example `16>=b>=8`, but for `18 >= b >= 8` it gets stuck again, unless the interval is broken with `||` cases again as a workaround for finite sets of $b$ values. Interesting, I'm not sure what's the tipping point and problem with $b$ being in intervals?

Comment: also try adding `b` before the other variables in the second argument of `Reduce` in your `integerSystem` and call it as `Timing[integerSystem[Reduce[8 <= b <= 100, Integers]]]`?

Comment: @kglr Still gets stuck in intervals if they are not small enough or split into parts via `||`. It's the same behaviour both locally and in the wolfram cloud.

Comment: Vepir, both `integerSystem[Reduce[8 <= b <= 100, Integers]]`  and `integerSystem2[8 <= b <= 100]` work without problem in version 9. In version 12 (WolframCloud) I could try only `8 <= b <= 18` and it is very slow. Since `Reduce[8<=b<=100, Integers]`  gives the same result  as `Or @@ Thread[b == Range[8, 100]]` you can use the latter instead (it is much faster too).